# Importing time module in python3

Tags: python-3.x, time, module

I have a problem when trying to import the time module in python3.

Can someone give me some hints? I searched in the [standard documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html?highlight=time#module-time) and it says it should be always available.

The error I get is:

```
>>>import time
ImportError: No module named 'time'
```

Comment: Which Python distribution are you using? Standard CPython, or something else (Jython, IronPython, ...)?

Comment: Can you import any of the other standard library modules?

Comment: Yes! I can import sys, os ...

Comment: What is the result of `import sys; 'time' in sys.modules`?

Comment: >>> import sys; 'time' in sys.modules
False

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling CPython? Is it the latest version (3.4.1)? Which OS are you on? How are you accessing it (IDLE, command line/Terminal)?

Answer (score 2):

`time` is a compiled shared object module. For example,

```
>>> import time
>>> time
<module 'time' from '/opt/ActivePython-2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/time.so'>
```

These shared object modules live under a specific directory (`lib-dynload` in the above case), which directory may not be in your $PYTHONPATH.